# how to write a macro can accept argument which is symbol

Tags: clojure, macros

I want to write a macro to accept a vector params

```
(defmacro eval-verify [body]
  `(cond
     ~@body
     :default nil))
```

it work in this case

```
(eval-verify [true 1 false 2])
```

it return 1,and i run

```
(macroexpand-1 '(eval-verify [true 1 false 2]))
```

it return

```
(clojure.core/cond true 1 false 2 :default nil)
```

it seems ok,but when i def a vector

```
(def a [true 1 false 2])
```

and run

```
(eval-verify a)
```

it is error

```
IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Symbol
```

how to write a macro can accept argument which is symbol,or write functoin can do the same things.

Answer (score 4):

Macro arguments are passed as unevaluated symbols. Therefore when you invoke `(eval-verify a)` the *symbol* a is the value of the body argument passed to `eval-verify` and not `[true 1 false 2]`. Since unquote-splice (~@) expects a Seq and it finds a symbol (a), you receive the IllegalArgumentException.

You would either need to invoke eval-verify using the form `(eval-verify [true 1 false 2])` or you would need to use a plain function.

You can use the following function instead of a macro:

```
(defn eval-verify [coll]
  (loop [[f v :as c] coll]
    (cond
      (and (ifn? f) (f)) v
      (and (not (ifn? f)) f) v
      :else (if (seq c) (recur (drop 2 c)) nil))))
```